# XSLT : Insert new line between two elements in a template

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, xslt, whitespace

I'm currently entering in the world of XSLT, because I've to make a transformation between two XML files.

I'm starting, but I face a small issue which make my files hardly readable on every generation.

I've as input an XML which is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ConfigurationNodes>
   <Versions>
      <PackagesA Version="1.8" />
      <PackageB Version="1.1" />
      <PackageC Version="1.7" />
   </Versions>
   <ConfigurationNode  Type="SomeSpecialType">
      <Name>MyName</Name>
      <Revision>0</Revision>
      <Description >The big full description here</Description>
   </ConfigurationNode>
</ConfigurationNodes>
```

On which I currently apply the following transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="ConfigurationNode[@Type='SomeSpecialType']">
    <Object Name="Configuration" NodeType="SomeOtherType">
      <Property Name="Name" Value="{Name/text()}" Type="System.String"/>
      <Property Name="Description" Value="{Description/text()}" Type="System.String"/>
      <Property Name="Revision" Value="{Revision/text()}" Type="System.Int32" />
    </Object>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This work, but currently my `Property` elements are on the same line(and in my real case, I've 10 property here):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ConfigurationNodes>
   <Versions>
      <PackagesA Version="1.8" />
      <PackageB Version="1.1" />
      <PackageC Version="1.7" />
   </Versions>
   <Object Name="Configuration" NodeType="SomeOtherType"><Property Name="Name" Value="MyName" Type="System.String" /><Property Name="Description" Value="The big full description here" Type="System.String" /><Property Name="Revision" Value="0" Type="System.Int32" /></Object>
</ConfigurationNodes>
```

My goal is to have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ConfigurationNodes>
   <Versions>
      <PackagesA Version="1.8" />
      <PackageB Version="1.1" />
      <PackageC Version="1.7" />
   </Versions>
   <Object Name="Configuration" NodeType="SomeOtherType">
      <Property Name="Name" Value="MyName" Type="System.String" />
      <Property Name="Description" Value="The big full description here" Type="System.String" />
      <Property Name="Revision" Value="0" Type="System.Int32" />
   </Object>
</ConfigurationNodes>
```

After some research, I've tried to put an `<xsl:preserve-space elements="*"/>`, with no luck.

I read everywhere people having the opposite issue(too much space), but I didn't find the same issue that I'm having.

I think you already guessed that I'm doing this transformation within Visual studio(msxsl namespace).

Comment: Well you have `<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />` so I am astonished your result is not indented. How do you run the transformation, directly in Visual Studio? Or do you write .NET code to run it in e.g. C# or VB? In that case show us the code you have, perhaps you are not using the `XslCompiledTransform` API correctly to make sure the `xsl:output` directive has an effect.

Comment: Yes I do it directly in Visual Studio( `Debug -> Start XSLT (Without) Debugging`). The weird things is that all the elements which are not concerned by this template have their indentation set properly. I tried to put the `indent` to false, it doesn't seems to change anything

Comment: If you do not show all of the code, nobody can try to reproduce your problem.

Comment: In the XSLT you have shown, the template that matches `ConfigurationNode` outputs a `Object`, but this is not shown in your actual (or even expected) output. Are you sure that another XSLT stylesheet isn't coming into play here? Thanks!

Comment: @MathiasMüller I add tomorrow the rest of the XML, but the XSD is complete.

Comment: @TimC Sorry my bad, I made an error while anonymizing the code. I corrected the code

Comment: @MathiasMüller Now the input XML/XSLT/Output are exactly what I'm trying right now. There is not a lot of new things

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't have a MSXML processor to test with, but I managed to produce the same problem using the *libxslt* processor.  Here, the issue can be solved by adding:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

to the top level of the stylesheet. This, BTW, should be almost always included if you're using the *identity transform* template.

Comment: This is actually working :). But I don't understand why, strip-space means that we remove space, right? so why specifying that we would like to remove space to all elements, it now has spaces?

Comment: @J4N Since this behavior is not consistent among all processors, I see very little point in trying to understand the logic behind it (assuming there *is* logic behind it).

Comment: Agreed, but I don't expect to have the opposite behavior ;). Any way, this solve my current issue.